# In_memory vs custom authentication provider

Tags: security, symfony

I have devellop my own authentification provider as founder [here](http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/).

I used to connect with the `in_memory` system, but now I can't login anymore with it. Did I miss something?

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Acme\SecurityBundle\User\WebServiceUser: plaintext
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            webservice-login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                provider: acme_provider
            logout: ~
    providers:
        multiples:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, acme_provider]
        acme_provider:
            id: acme_demo_user_provider
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    - { name: admin, password: pwd, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
```

Answer (score 2):

You specified to your `webservice-login` to use `acme_provider` instead of your `multiples` provider.

Try this:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Acme\SecurityBundle\User\WebServiceUser: plaintext
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            webservice-login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                provider: multiples
            logout: ~
    providers:
        multiples:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, acme_provider]
        acme_provider:
            id: acme_demo_user_provider
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    - { name: admin, password: pwd, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
```

The form will look to authenticate the user against the in_memory or the acme_provider